# Rust peekable double reference

Tags: rust, iterator

Why does a peekable iterator return a double reference in an Option?

```
struct Foo {}
let mut foovec = vec![];
foovec.push(Foo {});
let mut iter = foovec.iter().peekable();
let next = iter.peek();
```

`next` is an `Option<&&Foo>`, not an `Option<&Foo>`.

How do I get it to be the latter?

I do not want to use `.into_iter()` because I do not want to consume the vec. I just want a borrowed reference to the Foo struct wrapped in an Option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`peek` yields references to whatever you're iterating over. If that's also references, it'll yield double references. You can use the [`copied` Option adapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.copied) to remove that level of indirection:

```
struct Foo {}
let mut foovec = vec![];
foovec.push(Foo {});
let mut iter = foovec.iter().peekable();
// use `copied` here to go from Option<&&_> to Option<&_>
let next = iter.peek().copied();
```

Alternatively, you can just call `next` after you checked that you want the `peek`ed value:

```
struct Foo {}
let mut foovec = vec![];
foovec.push(Foo {});
let mut iter = foovec.iter().peekable();
if is_okay(iter.peek()) {
    let next = iter.next(); // `next` has type `&Foo`
}
```

You could even use pattern matching to remove one level of indirection:

```
if let Some(&next) = iter.peek() {
    // `next` has type `&Foo` in this block
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It appears that .copied() just extracts the reference, and does not actually copy the underlying Foo. Seems fairly efficient.

Comment: @ccleve It'll almost certainly compile down to a no-op.